# NGINX Not Serving "Fast" Stale Content with proxy_cache_background_update

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

We are running NGINX in front of our backend server.

We are attempting to enable the **proxy_cache_background_update** feature to allow NGINX to async updates to the cache and serve STALE content while it does this.

However, we are noticing that it still delivers STALE content slowly as if it's not serving from the cache.  The time it takes after an item expires is very slow and clearly not served from cache - you can tell it's going to the backend server, getting an update and delivering it to the client.

Here is our configuration from NGINX:

```
proxy_cache_revalidate on;
proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
proxy_cache_background_update   on;
```

Our backend server is delivering the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2019 21:07:09 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: max-age=1800, stale-while-revalidate=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

When attempting an expired page fetch we do notice the following header:

```
X-Cache: STALE
```

However, when providing this response it is very slow as if it's contacted the backend server and done it in realtime.

NGINX version:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.15.9
```

Any suggestions, tips and config changes are greatly appreciated.